# Specify Owner when creating jobs from Jenkins CLI

Tags: jenkins, groovy, command-line-interface

I have a groovy script that runs the command jenkins-cli create-job and uses an xml template to create a new maven job. In the template, I attempt to specify the owner using the jenkins ownership plugin, but this information is ignored. It appears that jenkins uses the default setting and sets the owner to the creator, which in this case is jenkins and thereby deployman. I'd like to somehow get around this and assign the proper own either by passing it on the command line or telling jenkins to ignore that default setting that sets the owner to the creator. Does anyone know how to do this?

Note: I have inspected the xml file passed on the command line and the config xml file of the new project in jenkins and run a diff between them. The only difference the the owner set to the wrong person.

Comment: Figured it out: Jenkins automatically sets the owner like I thought it did, to fix it, run a jerkins-cli update-job with the same template and it will assign the correct owner.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI
Read "Working with Credentials" section.

Also you can validate who is logged in with following jenkins cli command.

who-am-i : Reports your credential and permissions